# Rodrigues formula Associated Laguerre polynomial

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Could you find the rodriguez formula of 
$$L_n^{\beta }\left(x^2\right)$$ knowing that
$$\frac{\left(e^x x^{-\beta }\right) \frac{\partial ^n\left(e^{-x} x^{\beta }\right)}{\partial x^n}}{n!}=L_n^{\beta }(x)$$
Thanks

Comment: Is your goal to find the Rodrigues formula of $L_{n}^{\beta}(x^2)$?

Comment: Thanks to response so quick $$\left(f(x)=\frac{\partial ^ng(x)}{\partial x^n}\right) \left(f\left(x^2\right)=\frac{\partial ^n\text{g1}(x)}{\partial x^n}\right)$$ the problen it is to find g1(x).

Comment: Do you know how to derive it for $L_{n}^{\beta}$?

Comment: I mean $L_{n}^{\alpha}(x)$.

Comment: yes I know how to derivate .